# VB.Net binding filtered dataview to Listbox

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, data-binding

I am attempting to perform a filter on an Access database with Visual Studio 2010. The user will enter the search criteria into a textbox and I would like the results to be displayed in a listbox with the ability to update other fields depending on the selecteditem from the listbox. The current code I have is:

```
    Dim dv As New DataView

    With dv
        .Table = subcategoryDataSet.Tables("Subcategory")
        .AllowDelete = False
        .AllowEdit = False
        .AllowNew = False
        .RowFilter = "Description LIKE '" & txtSearchBox.Text & "*'"
        .Sort = "ID"
    End With

 'Now I am lost
```

Not sure if I need to create a datasource from the dv table? Or how to bind it properly to the listbox, or if I even need to bind it to the listbox?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply set the DataSource of the Listbox to your DataView and set the DisplayMember to the field that you want to see in the Listbox.

Something like this

```
ListBox1.DataSource = dv
ListBox1.DisplayMember = "Description"
```

Comment: Thank you for this Steve. I am now populating the listbox, but am populating with "System.Data.DataRowView" as the entry. I've been looking for conversion to String, but am of the mind I need something more than a string casting?

Comment: Did you set the DisplayMember property?

Comment: Yep, but then I misspelled my Column Header...FML...Thanks, Steve!

Comment: @Steve..in my case issue i am trying to do this thing in asp.net(vb.net) it is hitting on textchange event of textbox but it is not updating the radlistbox(telerik control). Please suggest.
 result = Session("mydt")
        Dim dv_ As DataView = result.DefaultView
        dv_.RowFilter = " abc like '%" & RadTextBox.Text & "%'"
        RadListBox.DataSource = dv_channel
        RadListBox.DataTextField = "abc"

Comment: @Developer I suggest you to post a new question with all the details of your problem. Eventually you could add a link to this question if you think that has relevance to solve your issue.